# Flask - I want a way to display task flowchart based on data from database

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I want to display some task process coming from an database, which has each task details and its predecessor tasks (which has to completed before proceeding to current task) in flask(python) as a flowchart.Its more like each task has some predecessor(may have multiple predecessor from different levels) which needs to be completed before doing next task

[image]
Something like in the image above. should be displayed on web page.(should be able to create a flowchart dynamically based on data as it can change).
How can I achieve this may be using flask,javascript or html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look on https://flowchart.js.org/.

Source here : https://github.com/adrai/flowchart.js

If you can provide some more informations about your tasks, we ll be able to help you tp generate the flow you want.

For your example mermaid will probably be easier : https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid

[image]

You can click on the picture it'll redirect you on the live editor.

Comment: Please refer the diagram in the question :   Each task has ID as shown. and "Predecessor" table has predecessor id for each of these task . i.e if you consider last step (ID:22) has predecessor 19,20,21

Comment: I updated my answer with another library, have a great day